# VB form buttons and their text

Tags: vb.net, forms, ms-access, button, connection

looking for help. I want to have a form with up to around 20 buttons. I want their display names to be coming from an access database table of products i sell. I can connect the form to my database and get the first record in the table to display on the first button but when i do the same for the second button it just displays the first record again. Is there a way of pointing the button name to the second record in the table some how? I dolnt want to hardcode the product names into the code as abviously they may change in the future :-)

thanks in advance

```
Public Class f

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'LoftDataSet.Services' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.ServicesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LoftDataSet.Services)

    'Loop through all the rows that are in the dataset
    For Each dr As DataRow In LoftDataSet.Services.Rows

        Dim btn As New Button 'Instantiate a button
        btn.Text = dr("service_name").ToString 'UserName is a field in my Users Table
        btn.Size = New Size(60, 40)
        btn.Tag = dr("ID") 'Here we set the tag to the primary key (ID)

        'Since we're using a flowlayoutpanel, we don't need to worry about setting the location property
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn) 'Add the button to the flow layout panel
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf UserClick  'Here we give the button a handler for the click event

    Next
End Sub

'Here we write our method for the click event of the button(s) we created

Private Sub UserClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    'We set a filter to the binding source passing it ID=<and whatever is stored in the tag property>

    ServicesBindingSource.Filter = "ID = " & DirectCast(sender, Button).Tag.ToString

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no way to know whats wrong with your code without the code.  Also if it is VB.NET it is not access-vba and vice versa. See [Ask]

Comment: i am using vb studio and i have connected to a .mdb and connection is ok

Comment: You have asked this question already albeit your data in that question was in a text file. You need to show your code.... I assume you are reading in data but not looping through each record to populate your buttons... and so you get the first record in all your buttons...

Comment: ok i have pasted in the code. thanks

Comment: Mych does my code help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Public Class f
02

03
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
04
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'LoftDataSet.Services' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
05
        Me.ServicesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LoftDataSet.Services)
06

07
        'Loop through all the rows that are in the dataset
08
        For Each dr As DataRow In LoftDataSet.Services.Rows
09

10
            Dim btn As New Button 'Instantiate a button
11
            btn.Text = dr("service_name").ToString 'UserName is a field in my Users Table
12
            btn.Size = New Size(140, 80)
13
            btn.Tag = dr("ID") 'Here we set the tag to the primary key (ID)
14

15
            'Since we're using a flowlayoutpanel, we don't need to worry about setting the location property
16
            FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn) 'Add the button to the flow layout panel
17
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf UserClick  'Here we give the button a handler for the click event
18

19
        Next
20
    End Sub
21

22
    Public Class Product
23
        Public Property ProductName As String
24
        Public Property ProductCost As Decimal
25

26
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
27
            Return ProductCost & " " & ProductName
28
            'Here you could build a formatted string to the user to include cost
29
        End Function
30
    End Class
31

32

33
    'Here we write our method for the click event of the button(s) we created
34
    Dim SelectedProduct As New Product
35

36

37
    Private Sub UserClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
38

39
        'We set a filter to the binding source passing it ID=
40

41
        ServicesBindingSource.Filter = "ID = " & DirectCast(sender, Button).Tag.ToString
42

43
        SelectedProduct.ProductName = DirectCast(sender, Button).Text
44
        SelectedProduct.ProductCost = DirectCast(ServicesBindingSource(0), DataRowView).DataView(0)(2)
45
        ListBox1.Items.Add(SelectedProduct)
46

47
    End Sub
48

49
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
50
        For i As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
51
            ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndices(i))
52
        Next
53
    End Sub
54